# Why does a combination of fontenc and inputenc creates a dim text

Tags: texmaker, input-encodings, font-encodings

I wrote the following and got a dim text in TEX maker:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.0cm,right=2.0cm,top=\dimexpr15mm+1.5\baselineskip,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%creates dim font in local tex softwares
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalize]{cleveref}
\usepackage{xurl}
 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5mm} 

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhfoffset[L]{1cm}
\fancyhfoffset[R]{1cm} 
\rhead{\bfseries  Alpha beta}
\lhead{\bfseries abcd}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{[\arabic{footnote}]}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{flushleft}
    
\end{flushleft}
    \fontsize{20pt}{10pt}\selectfont
    \textsc{\textbf{Something Something}}
\end{center}
 

Some text goes on here for a dim text check.

\end{document}
```

and got the following output:

[image: dim text]

And when I remove fontenc package, then I get the following output:

[image: non dim text]

My question:

1. Why is this problem occurring?
2. What should I do to remove this problem of non-compatibility?

Thanks!

Comment: My crystal ball tells me you're using MiKTeX. Did it get right?

Comment: @egreg, Yeah, this problem is occurring in MiKTeX or Tex maker. But when I write the same thing in overleaf, it works! I think it is a software issue. Are there any suggestions to get rid of such thing.

Comment: install the cm-super package in miktex